# Pattern based filter except one route

Tags: php, laravel, filter, laravel-routing

I have these filters in place

```
Route::when('app/*', 'auth');
Route::when('app/*', 'filled_basic_info');
```

The "filled_basic_info" filter redirects the user to the 'users.personal' route if the basic information of the user is not yet filled.

The 'users.personal' route leads to the "app/personal" url.

My question is, how do I set the 'filled_basic_info' filter to be applied on all the routes that lead to 'app/*' except the 'users.personal' route?

I have tried

```
Route::when('app/*', 'filled_basic_info', array('except' => 'users.personal'));
```

but it doesn't work.

I'd love to avoid grouping all the 'app/*' routes as I would need to do that on all the packages I have in place.

Thank you.

Answer (score 0):

I ended up editing the filter like so:

```
Route::filter('filled_basic_info', function()
{
    if (empty(Auth::user()->first_name) || empty(Auth::user()->last_name))
    {
        if(!(Route::currentRouteName() == "user.personal"))
            return Redirect::route('user.personal')->withAlerts(['Please enter your name below to continue.']);
    }
});
```